# JBoss war file deployment issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy a KM.war file on jboss server. Its getting following error trace.

```
16:12:07,680 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///F:/software/servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/OpenKM.war state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///F:/software/servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/defau
lt/deploy/KM.war
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/F:/software/servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/OpenKM.war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-common-utilities-2.5.1.jar/org/apache/cxf/common/util/ReflectionUtil$6.class"
        at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:268) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error visiting resource: VFSResourceContext @ org/apache/cxf/common/util/ReflectionUtil$6.class / BaseClassLoader@eb9464{vfs:///F:/software/servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/OpenKM.war}, visitor: org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.GenericAnnotationVisitor@6e1c9a
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.IgnoreSetErrorHandler.handleError(IgnoreSetErrorHandler.java:56) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:922) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:32) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:56) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:72) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:72) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:91) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:147) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:25) [:1.6.0_35]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:50) [:1.6.0_35]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:236) [:1.6.0_35]
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:230) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:218) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_35]
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getMethods(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:217) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.ClassInfoImpl.getDeclaredMethods(ClassInfoImpl.java:416) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.handleClass(ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.java:80) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:108) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
        ... 60 more

16:12:11,581 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable
```

- Windows Enviroment,
- jboss-6.0.0.Final
- war file size is 99MB

war file is a project based on hibernates, spring security and mvc framework.

Answer (score 3):

JBOSS 6.0 use JBOSS WS-CXF 3.1.4. This version of JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF is based on Apache CXF 2.3.1. And you are using cxf-common-utilities-2.5.1.jar. Remove this jar and redeploy the application.

Comment: Hi Shashi,I am facing same exception."Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/D:/XY/jboss_61/server/xyz/deploy/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar/org/jfree/chart/ChartFrame.class" Can you please suggest me something on this?One more thing is that, this application runs well on my local.I am facing it on test server.