# exception when deploying using maven plugin

Tags: maven, glassfish, maven-plugin

Im trying to deploy to glasshfish 4 server using maven plugin and it throws the following exception. Does anyone know what might have gone wrong from reading this exception?

```
[2013-10-02T18:47:02.710+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1380732422710] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Enclosing method not found
java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:944)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isNonStaticInnerClass(Reflections.java:383)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.isTypeManagedBeanOrDecoratorOrInterceptor(Beans.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:223)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBeans(BeanDeployer.java:202)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]
```

Comment: Any hints in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705882/jboss-war-file-deployment-issue ?

Comment: Not sure how that would help?

Comment: It's a very similar error which was caused by having two copies of the same class present. Might that be the case here?